# Simple regexp inside emacs keyboard macro

Tags: regular-expressions, keyboard-macros

Newbie question: I'm trying to record a keyboard macro with a simple regexp inside (`search-backward-regexp ^[0-9]`). This works well when recording the macro, but as soon as I try to execute it, the search fails because emacs puts the brackets twice (message `Search failed: "^[[0-9]]"`). How do I do this right?

Comment: It could be a problem with something like `electric-pair-mode`. Can you try using Emacs with no init file (`emacs -q`) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: What @DoMiNeLa10 said: try to repro using `emacs -Q`. And please show the relevant part of your actual code. The sexp you show can't be the one in the code - the arg to `search-backward-regexp` must be a string, for example.

Comment: A possible workaround would be to use `C-q [` to enter the `[`

Comment: Also, did you record the macro in the same buffer you executed it in?